# Which Linux distribution to choose for creating a USB boot-repair-disk?

Tags: boot-repair

[boot-repair-disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) is a live disc image that contains the [boot-repair](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/) utility. I'm creating a live USB with this disc image using Universal USB Installer.

The first step is to select the Linux Distribution that matches the disc image. There is a drop-box containing Ubuntu, Fedora, etc.

Which Linux distribution should I select?

Comment: Select Ubuntu..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot-Repair-Disk is based on Lubuntu, so select Ubuntu.